# Session doesn't stick for long time

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state, stateserver

I have an ASP site where the session would expire within 30 minutes or sometimes less. The Session mode was 'InProc', so I changed it to 'StateServer', and also started the 'ASP.NET State Service', but I am still running into similar issues. I also changed the application pool's 'Idle Time-out' to '0'.

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424" stateNetworkTimeout="20" />
```

Any idea why the session is expiring or not sticking around after leaving the application idle for about 30 minutes or less?

Thanks.
Sanjeev

Answer (score 2):

There is a session timeout you can set, it takes number of minutes.

```
<sessionState ... timeout="60"  />
```